# How to keep words in a column in a data set according to words in another data set?

Tags: r, dataset

I am very new to the language R. I have a simple problem I can't seem to solve:
I have two 2D data sets called *airlines* and *flights*. I want to substitute the "two letter carrier abbreviation" in the data frame *flights* by the full name that you can find in the data frame *airlines*. In the *airlines* data frame the abbreviation and the full name have the same row, but not column.

Can anyone give me any advice? I have been trying to put it in a for loop and use the function `gsub()` but haven't solved it yet. Any help would be a lifesaver!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that illustrates your problem? Also show expected output.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
combo <- flights %>%
 left_join(airlines)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newdf <- merge(x = flights,
               y = airlines,
               by.x = 'two_letter_carrier_abbreviation', #abbreviation column from flights
               by.y = 'two_letter_carrier_abbreviation', #abbreviation column from airlines
               all.x = TRUE,  #keep all rows in flights
               all.y = FALSE) #don't add full names that are not found in flights

newdf$two_letter_carrier_abbreviation <- NULL #remove the abbreviation column
```